# The isPDFEmbedded tag in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

What's the purpose of the isPDFEmbedded tag in Jasper Reports

Answer (score 5):

You can specify if you need embedded fonts in the pdf export of your report. Embedding fonts into pdf increases the size of the pdf, but pdf viewer will show the correct font even if the font is not installed on the client's computer. [Here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21083) you can find more info about pdf font strategies.

Answer (score 4):

isPDFEmbedded tag is like a flag that specifies whether the font should be embedded into the document itself. It defaults to false.